# How can I add new techs I dislike in the Jobs profile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, bug-reporting-process

If I click the last tag, enter text mode, shift the cursor to the right then enter <kbd>space</kbd> to try and add a new tag, my cursor just disappears and I get back to the state where I started.

Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> only seems to switch through suggestions of existing tag.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed with our recent updates to the job search page. Thank you for reporting this!